# Library Error When Running Matlab code in java packaged using library compiler in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I have compiled the MATLAB code to Java package using "deploytool" command. When using the library in Java I get error as library not found as shown below.

I am using Java 1.8.0_144, 64 bit, MATLAB is 64 bit and also the java used for running the library is also 64 bit. I included the JavaBuilder.jar and my MATLAB jar in the libraries section in intellij settings. I am also loading the "mclmcrrt9_4.dll" file in resources, class path, also loading it by using
`System.loadLibrary("mclmcrrt9_4");`

Any help regarding this or any other methods to convert MATLABcode to java is helpful

Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the required library mclmcrrt9_4.dll on java.library.path.
This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MATLAB Runtime. Its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or 
the current path configuration, or a mismatch with the architecture of the Java interpreter on the path.
MATLAB Runtime version this component is attempting to use: 9.4.
Java interpreter architecture: win64.
```

Comment: Sounds like a path error. The system is looking for the `mclmcrrt9_4.dll` on your `java.library.path`. Can you check that this is on your path? What MATLAB release are you using? It is looking for MATLAB R2018a (9.4). If you deployed the software on a different release, it might be the cause

Comment: I have checked and added in the path you mentioned, but i get the same error and also i am using MATLAB R2018a (9.4)